# unified function for a sequence of replace functions

Tags: python, pandas

I applied some sequence of functions on a variable of my dataframe. The variable 'var' of my dataframe is like this:

```py
df['var'].head()
0     R$ 140.284,04
1    R$ -200.131,47
2     R$ -77.837,78
3     R$ 524.782,95
4     R$ 871.251,02
Name: var, dtype: object
```

I would like to replace:

1. "R$" by "" (In other words, drop "R$")
2. "." by "" (In other words, drop ".")
3. "," by "."
4. convert as float

I tryed somthing like this:

```py
def rep1(x):
    return(x.replace('R$',''))


def rep2(x):
    return(x.replace('.',''))

def as_float(x):
    return(float(x.replace(',','.')))


df['var'] = df['var'].map(rep1)
df['var'] = df['var'].map(rep2)
df['var'] = df['var'].map(as_float)
```

Note that for these to work, I had to keep the order shown above when applying the sequence of functions. This really works, but I would like a shorter and more elegant syntax. Also, I wish I could apply the same procedure to more than one variable at one time. Something like this:

```py
df['var', 'var2'] = df['var', 'var2'].map(my_unified_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a chain `replace` , we need call `replace` in pandas twice

```
pd.to_numeric(df['var'].replace({'[R$]':'','[.]':''},regex=True).replace({',':'.'},regex=True))
Out[361]: 
0    140284.04
1   -200131.47
2    -77837.78
3    524782.95
4    871251.02
Name: var, dtype: float64
```

Comment: One by one variable, it really works. But, when I do this: df['renda_L','renda_B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['renda_L','renda_B'].replace({'[R$]':'','[.]':''},regex=True).replace({',':'.'},regex=True)). I get a error.